# Search Postgres Array (text[]) Field with Rails Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, postgresql

I have a postgres database with a table that has a field that holds a text array (the definition is text[]). I want to search this field with an rails array. For example:

The table would have two records: 
Record 1: id=>1, equip_numbers=>{885, 887, 900}
Record 2: id=>2, equip_numbers=>{678, 789, 890}
Record 3: id=>3, equip_numbers=>{885, 887}

Array from program would be: equips = [885, 887, 900]

I want to search the table to find the record that includes all the numbers from the equipment table above (So just record 1 not record 2 or 3).

I have read about using ANY or ALL but those are all for single value searches 
(Equipment.where("'885' = ANY (equip_numbers)")). I want to do something like:

Equipment.where("#{equips} IN ANY (equip_numbers))

but that doesn't work. How would I use the equips array to search the equip_numbers field in the Equipment table?

Comment: Would `{885,887,900,1111}` also be a match? Does order matter in the array or are the arrays treated like sets?

Comment: {885,887,900,1111} would not be a set, and no order doesn't matter.

Comment: So you want the arrays to be equal set-wise (i.e. no repetitions, order doesn't matter)?

Comment: Yes, and I figured out what to do. I found this website: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-array.html that helped figure out what operators to use.